# "Program is not a recognized executable" error in Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse

I'm trying to debug a C++ programme in Eclipse Indigo. The project is using autotools/configure (and the respective plugin) as build system.

After successful build I right-clicked on the binary in the project browser and chose "Debug As". Then I used the file browser to select the binary. Clicking on "Debug" then opens a dialog which just says "program is not a recognized executable".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I found the answer: the binary parsers configured in eclipse were the wrong ones. Adding the correct binary parser under Project --> Properties --> C/C++ Build --> Settings solves he problem.

Comment: And which are the binary parsers? I am the same problem ;)

Comment: Whops, solved! Unchecked the Elf parser and checked Mach-O 64 parser and it debugs! Thanks!

Comment: I'm seeing the same problem, but unchecking Elf and checking Mach-O 64 doesn't solve it.

Comment: on windows, "Binary Parsers" -> "PE Windows Parser" works for me.

Comment: I am on Linux Mint and i chose GNU elf parser. But it made no difference.

Comment: I actually had the same problem (I was using CMake to configure). My solution was the same as yours, however, the build settings were found under: Project -> Properties -> C/C++ Make Project -> Binary Parser. By default a deprecated Mach-O Parser was selected.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using `libtool` in your project, what looks like the binary may actually be a wrapper script used to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and stuff like that before executing the real binary (which is stored in the `.libs` directory). This may be what causes Eclipse to fail, but I'm not sure how you should go about fixing that.

There seem to be a bit of documentation about Eclipse CDT and `libtool` on the internet which may have the infos you need though: http://www.freerdp.com/wiki/doku.php?id=eclipse#debug_configuration

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but libtool is not involved. The file is an executable (Mach-O executable i386, I'm using gcc 4.6.1 on Mac OS X).

Comment: I have the same issue and setting binary parser didn't resolve. It turns out that what i thought of as executable was exactly a wrapper script using libtool. So probably above mentioned cause is correct. I am trying to figure out how to fix it. I verified this when i manually tried running gdb on exe after failing to run it from eclipse

Answer (score 0):

From OSX snow leopard on, gcc seems to build 64 bit executables by default. And those won’t be recognized from Eclipse in return. To solve the error, you’ve got to explicitly set your architecture to i386.

Enter your project properties and add the command line option “-arch i386″ for each C++ Linker, C++ Compiler and C Compiler. After a clean build, you should be clear to debug again. In Linker options make sure to NOT set it up as -Xlinker option.

[Original Source](http://blog.christianleberfinger.de/?p=167)